# Await in Nestjs Mongoose Update/Delete

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Hy all.
Why article.service.ts without "await" doesn't persist update/delete to mongodb?

**article.service.ts**

```
async update(id: string, updateArticleDto: UpdateArticleDto) {    
  await this.articleModel.updateOne({_id: id}, updateArticleDto);        
}

async remove(id: string) {
  await this.articleModel.deleteOne({_id: id});     
}
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Because `updateOne` and `deleteOne` are asynchronous functions, and we use await to wait for a promise to resolve the result. for more details check this [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/async-await-javascript-5038668ec6eb#:%7E:text=Async%20functions%20enable%20us%20to,without%20blocking%20the%20execution%20thread.&text=Using%20async%20simply%20implies%20that,resolved%20promise%20with%20its%20value.)